# RSA Archer: Get mail's attachments with mail monitor data feed

Tags: datafeed, archer, rsa-archer-grc

I have made a mail monitor data feed to create records from mails sent by users. So far I could only copy the content of those mails and not any documents that have been attached to the mails.
I checked the transform file used by the data feed and there is no trace of attachments. And when checking the eml file generated by the data feed in the data feed directory there is also no trace of them. The files are also not copied to the file repository.

Does someone know if there is a way to customize the data feed to have it take the documents from a mail and attach them to a record?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Paco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paco, currently the mail monitor data feeds cannot consume attachments.

Feel free to upvote the enhancement here, https://community.rsa.com/ideas/1423